# Display different fab depending on active View of TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

If PageA is selected, fabA should be displayed. If PageB is selected, fabB respectively.
Whats the best way to achieve this?

```
var fabA = FloatingActionButton();
var fabB = FloatingActionButton();
```

...

```
Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          PageA(),
          PageB(),
        ]),
        floatingActionButton: fabA,
      )
```

Comment: I think there's an example of exactly this in the flutter gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can declare a `List<FloatingActionButton>` and return based on `tabController.index` 
code snippet

```
_tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length)
          ..addListener(() {
            if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
              print(
                  "tab is animating. from active (getting the index) to inactive(getting the index) ");
            } else {             
              setState(() {});
...           
floatingActionButton: floatButton[_tabController.index],
...
List<FloatingActionButton> floatButton = [
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.share),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarBottomSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppBarBottomSampleState createState() => _AppBarBottomSampleState();
}

class _AppBarBottomSampleState extends State<AppBarBottomSample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length)
      ..addListener(() {
        if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
          print(
              "tab is animating. from active (getting the index) to inactive(getting the index) ");
        } else {
          //tab is finished animating you get the current index
          //here you can get your index or run some method once.
          print(_tabController.index);
          setState(() {});
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _nextPage(int delta) {
    final int newIndex = _tabController.index + delta;
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= _tabController.length) return;
    _tabController.animateTo(newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AppBar Bottom Widget'),
          leading: IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Previous choice',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              _nextPage(-1);
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              tooltip: 'Next choice',
              onPressed: () {
                _nextPage(1);
              },
            ),
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(48.0),
            child: Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.white),
              child: Container(
                height: 48.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: TabPageSelector(controller: _tabController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: floatButton[_tabController.index],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<FloatingActionButton> floatButton = [
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.share),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.create),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.repeat),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.forward),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.link),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  )
];

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'CAR', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'BICYCLE', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'BOAT', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'BUS', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'TRAIN', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'WALK', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(AppBarBottomSample());
}
```